# Is it possible to restrict who can see a question by requiring a non-disclosure agreement?

Tags: discussion

As game design related questions are more closer to the user experience when playing the game, one could need to allow access to a playable prototype.

But there is always the problem on how to avoid that information being disclosed.

Answer (score 11):

[No.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html)

*Any question which is so specific to your situation as to require an NDA and access to one of your builds, would be considered too localised a question for archiving on stack exchange, and would likely be closed for that reason.*

Additionally, why would people want to put themselves under a legal obligation to you in order to answer your questions, for no gain to themselves?  If you're in a position where you require people to sign an NDA, you probably need to start actually paying people for their time and effort.

Comment: hmm... good point. what if I ask a question and add a link where I require the acceptance of the NDA to download the demo, is this allowed by SE, or could eventually be the question be closed?

Comment: Highly discouraged. My recommendation/opinion and general consensus: Questions should stand on their own, and any extra links or material should be totally optional supplementary material (someone who reads and understands the question should be able to answer it without clicking links). I'm not going to say it's disallowed, and closing is generally up to the community users where it's not a clear violation of rules, but I don't think it will be well-received and I expect nobody would sign the NDA. I certainly wouldn't want to be legally bound to something just to answer a question.

Comment: Anyway, I also think such an NDA would be extremely hard to enforce. Especially an internet NDA. Why bother with it? We've all seen that game ideas can be copied, just changing assets around (Zynga). Either you're willing to show your demo to people to get an answer, or you should write a question with adequate material (screenshots maybe) that someone can answer the question without playing the demo.